# Using static_cast and then dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, void-pointers, dynamic-cast, static-cast

I'm dealing with a special case where I can't use `dynamic_cast` directly because the object is a `void*`. Is using first `static_cast` on it and then `dynamic_cast` (on the result of the `static_cast`) bad practice? Is it wrong?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
MyClass* CastVoidPtr(void* pVoidPtr)
{
    // casting it to MyClass so we could use dynamic_cast
    MyClass* pTemp = static_cast<MyClass*>(pVoidPtr);

    // returning the actual result that will make sure that we have a MyClass object or a nullptr
    return dynamic_cast<MyClass*>(pTemp);
}
```

Comment: `pTemp` is already a `MyClass*`, what do you expect the `dynamic_cast` to do here? Your comment doesn't make sense - if `pVoidPtr` were a nullptr, then `pTemp` would be also, so you could still just return it.

Comment: if `pVoidPtr` isn't of the `MyClass` type won't `pTemp` be non-null?

Comment: Original comment: Just to enhance @Barry's comment: `return dynamic_cast<MyClass*>(pVoidPtr);` shall do the job. See the answers for more details. Edited comment: Oh I did not know that this wouldn't be possible. Forget my comment.

Comment: @RolandSarrazin You can't `dynamic_cast` a `void` pointer.

Comment: @RolandSarrazin if only Bjarne would allow it :(

Comment: @IosifMurariu No. It's a `void*`, how would the compiler know whether or not it's actually a `MyClass*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would depend on how the pointer got to be a `void*` to begin with. If it was cast to the `void*` from the same type as be cast to (here `MyClass*`), then yes, this cast is fine and works as expected;

From [cppreference on `static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast):

> A prvalue of type pointer to `void` (possibly cv-qualified) can be converted to pointer to any type. If the value of the original pointer satisfies the alignment requirement of the target type, then the resulting pointer value is unchanged, otherwise it is unspecified. Conversion of any pointer to pointer to `void` and back to pointer to the original (or more cv-qualified) type preserves its original value.

Using `static_cast` in this way is essentially saying to the compiler "I know it is this type - trust me", and the compiler obliges.

The `dynamic_cast` can then be evaluated after this. It is typically used to cast to a more derived type. Here, you are casting to the same type - it is not doing anything particularly useful. If the type was a more derived type (e.g. `MySpecialisedClass`), then it would be fine.

---

As it stands, the function can be simplified to:

```
MyClass* CastVoidPtr(void* pVoidPtr)
{
    return static_cast<MyClass*>(pVoidPtr);
}
```

Or to simply use a naked `static_cast<>`.

---

A side note; worth mentioning here for completeness is that [`reinterpret_cast` has similar functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast);

> Any pointer to object of type `T1` can be converted to pointer to object of another type `cv T2`. This is exactly equivalent to `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(expression))` (which implies that if `T2`'s alignment requirement is not stricter than `T1`'s, the value of the pointer does not change and conversion of the resulting pointer back to its original type yields the original value). In any case, the resulting pointer may only be dereferenced safely if allowed by the type aliasing rules ...